# Linq Query taking so long to execute

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my linq query and this is taking so long to execute. can any one suggest me how to make it faster . i am using some function in this query for calculating the data on the fly . when i removed those function this query run fast but i have to use those function for getting data in that right way . please some one suggest me how  i can improve this query

```
  var l = from a in GetItemList(con)
                        join product in GetProductStock(con) on
                            a.Id
                            equals product.Id
                            into prodList
                        from prod in prodList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join brand in GetBrandStock(con) on
                            a.PbPairId equals brand.Id
                            into brandList
                        from bran in brandList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join pack in GetPackStock(con) on
                            a.PbpPairId equals pack.Id
                            into packList
                        from pac in packList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join np in RtbVoucherVoPurSalItem.GetTotalBuySellByItemForNormal(con) on a.Id equals np.ItemId
                            into npl
                        from npv in npl.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join pp in RtbVoucherVoPurSalItem.GetTotalBuySellByItemForNormal(con) on a.Id equals pp.ItemId
                            into ppl
                        from ppv in ppl.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select
                            new RsXtraProductListWithClosing
                                {
                                    Id = a.Id,
                                    PbPairId = a.PbPairId,
                                    PbpPairId = a.PbpPairId,
                                    ProductId = a.ProductId,
                                    BrandId = a.BrandId,
                                    PackId = a.PackId,
                                    DesignNoId = a.DesignNoId,
                                    Product = a.Product.Trim(),
                                    Brand = a.Brand.Trim(),
                                    Pack = a.Pack.Trim(),
                                    DesignNo = a.DesignNo.Trim(),
                                    QuantityUnitId = a.QuantityUnitId,
                                    RateUnitId = a.RateUnitId,
                                    AskDesignNo = a.AskDesignNo,
                                    AskCustomSize = a.AskCustomSize,
                                    AskDesignNoRate = a.AskDesignNoRate,
                                    UseBachNumber = a.UseBachNumber,
                                    UseExpDate = a.UseExpDate,
                                    UseManfacDate = a.UseManfacDate,
                                    AskD = a.AskD,
                                    AskH = a.AskH,
                                    AskW = a.AskW,
                                    SaD = a.SaD,
                                    SaH = a.SaH,
                                    SaW = a.SaW,
                                    SaleByPump = a.SaleByPump,
                                    ScalGroup = a.ScalGroup,
                                    CalculationUnitId = a.CalculationUnitId,
                                    UnitSize = a.UnitSize,
                                    LowStockQuantity = a.LowStockQuantity,
                                    OverStockQuantity = a.OverStockQuantity,
                                    SizeAs = a.SizeAs,
                                    UseDirectDiscount = a.UseDirectDiscount,
                                    Discount = a.Discount,
                                    PurchaseRate1 = a.PurchaseRate1,
                                    PurchaseRate2 = a.PurchaseRate2,
                                    PurchaseRate3 = a.PurchaseRate3,
                                    PurchaseOtherRate = a.PurchaseOtherRate,
                                    SaleRate1 = a.SaleRate1,
                                    SaleRate2 = a.SaleRate2,
                                    SaleRate3 = a.SaleRate3,
                                    SaleOtherRate = a.SaleOtherRate,
                                    LockOtherPurchaseRate = a.LockOtherPurchaseRate,
                                    LockOtherSaleRate = a.LockOtherSaleRate,
                                    LockSaleRate = a.LockSaleRate,
                                    LockPurchaseRate = a.LockPurchaseRate,
                                    ProductClosingStock = ((a.Pobu ?? prod.OpeningStock ?? 0) + (npv.Quantaty ?? 0)),
                                    ProductCClosingStock = ((a.CPobu ?? prod.COpeningStock ?? 0) + (ppv.Quantaty ?? 0)),
                                    BrandClosingStock = ((a.Bobu ?? bran.OpeningStock ?? 0) + (npv.Quantaty ?? 0)),
                                    BrandCClosingStock = ((a.CBobu ?? bran.COpeningStock ?? 0) + (ppv.Quantaty ?? 0)),
                                    PackClosingStock = ((a.Paobu ?? pac.OpeningStock ?? 0) + (npv.Quantaty ?? 0)),
                                    PackCClosingStock = ((a.CPaobu ?? pac.COpeningStock ?? 0) + (ppv.Quantaty ?? 0)),
                                    DesignNoClosingStock = ((a.Dobu ?? 0) + (npv.Quantaty ?? 0)),
                                    DesignNoCClosingStock = ((a.CDobu ?? 0) + (ppv.Quantaty ?? 0))
                                };
                return l;


and this are the other functions helping this query 

  public static IQueryable<RsXtraOpeningStock> GetPackStock(RdbCompany con)
        {
            return con.RtbInventoryProductBrandPackDesignNoPairs
                .GroupBy(p => p.BrandPackPairId).Select(
                g => new RsXtraOpeningStock
                         {
                             Id = g.Key,
                             OpeningStock = (g.Sum(m => m.OpeningStock) ?? 0),
                             COpeningStock = (g.Sum(m => m.COpenigStock) ?? 0),
                         });
        }


        public static IQueryable<RsXtraOpeningStock> GetBrandStock(RdbCompany con)
        {
            return from d in con.RtbInventoryProductBrandPackPairs
                   join pk in GetPackStock(con) on d.Id equals pk.Id
                       into pkl
                   from pkd in pkl.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   group new{d,pkd} by d.BrandPairId
                       into g
                       select new RsXtraOpeningStock
                       {
                           Id = g.Key,
                           OpeningStock = ((g.Sum(a => (decimal?)(a.d.OpeningStock ?? a.pkd.OpeningStock))??0)),
                           COpeningStock = ((g.Sum(a => (decimal?)(a.d.COpenigStock ?? a.pkd.COpeningStock))??0))
                       };
        }


        public static IQueryable<RsXtraOpeningStock> GetProductStock(RdbCompany con)
        {
            return from d in con.RtbInventoryProductBrandPairs
                   join br in GetBrandStock(con) on d.Id equals br.Id
                       into brl
                   from brd in brl.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   group new { d, brd } by d.ProductId
                       into g
                       select new RsXtraOpeningStock
                       {
                           Id = g.Key,
                           OpeningStock = ((g.Sum(a => (decimal?)(a.d.OpeningStock ?? a.brd.OpeningStock)) ?? 0)),
                           COpeningStock = ((g.Sum(a => (decimal?)(a.d.COpenigStock ?? a.brd.COpeningStock)) ?? 0))
                       };

        }






 public static IQueryable<RsXtraItemFinalBuySellByMode> GetTotalBuySellByItemForPure(RdbCompany con)
        {
            var stockActiveArray = RsXtraVoucherHelperArray.GetActiveStockVoucherType();
            return GetList(con).Where(
                a => stockActiveArray.Contains(a.FkVoucherVoMain.FkVoucher.FkVoucherGroup.VoucherType)
                     && a.FkVoucherVoMain.CompanyId == RsXtraMainInnerObj.CurrentCompany.Id
                     && a.FkVoucherVoMain.BranchId == RsXtraMainInnerObj.CurrentHierarchy.Id
                     && a.FkVoucherVoMain.Mode == RenumMode.P
                )
                .GroupBy(a => new {a.ItemId})
                .Select(a => new RsXtraItemFinalBuySellByMode
                                 {
                                     ItemId = a.Key.ItemId,
                                     Quantaty = a.Sum(c => (decimal?)c.Quantaty)
                                 });
        }


         public static IQueryable<RsXtraItemFinalBuySellByMode> GetTotalBuySellByItemForNormal(RdbCompany con)
        {
            var stockActiveArray = RsXtraVoucherHelperArray.GetActiveStockVoucherType();
            return GetList(con).Where(
                a => stockActiveArray.Contains(a.FkVoucherVoMain.FkVoucher.FkVoucherGroup.VoucherType)
                     && a.FkVoucherVoMain.CompanyId == RsXtraMainInnerObj.CurrentCompany.Id
                     && a.FkVoucherVoMain.BranchId == RsXtraMainInnerObj.CurrentHierarchy.Id
                     && a.FkVoucherVoMain.Mode != RenumMode.P
                )
                .GroupBy(a => new { a.ItemId })
                .Select(a => new RsXtraItemFinalBuySellByMode
                {
                    ItemId = a.Key.ItemId,
                    Quantaty = a.Sum(c => (decimal?)c.Quantaty)
                });
        }
```

Comment: I suspect that all these `GroupBy` statements either create a monstrous SQL statement containing many `CROSS JOIN` clauses, or emits large numbers of SQL statements. You'll have to check Sql Server Profiler. You probably should break up this task in a couple of LINQ statements.

Answer (score 0):

If using Linq to SQL, you can see what SQL statement exactly generated through SQL Server Profile. You can base on that to optimize it. But joining so much objects, the performance can be lost obviously.

Comment: ya but with this query . VS not showing sql statement

Comment: @sourabhdevpura not VS, run SQL Server Profiler (standalone program) to see what is really going on on server. What queryes are generated and how long they take. VS would not show You that.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll find that your helper functions are being re-evaluated each time they're called by the main query, you should be able to confirm this by doing a ToString() on your main query and check the method syntax generated by the compiler. If I were you I would cache the results of the helpers for each possible input beforehand and store the results in Dictionaries that your main query can then look-up in O(1) time.